# How to change ID to Ping (PyCharm, Python 3.9)

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

I have made this snipe command (From a Stackoverflow question) but when the bot answers, the title says the ID of the author of the deleted message, not the ping or name. How do I change it?

Code:

```
snipe_message_content = None
snipe_message_author = None
snipe_message_id = None

@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):

    global snipe_message_content
    global snipe_message_author
    global snipe_message_id

    snipe_message_content = message.content
    snipe_message_author = message.author.id
    snipe_message_id = message.id
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

    if message.id == snipe_message_id:
        snipe_message_author = None
        snipe_message_content = None
        snipe_message_id = None

@bot.command()
async def snipe(message):
    if snipe_message_content is None:
        await message.channel.send("Theres nothing to snipe.")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Asked by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_author(name=f"<@{snipe_message_author}>")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't ping a user in the `author` part of an embed. However, you can say their name, so that is what we'll do.

### Author Name

Getting the author name is as simple as changing the `snipe_message_author = message.author.id` (which gets the ID), to `snipe_message_author = message.author.name`.

### Displaying Author Name

To display the author name with a nice format, remove the "<@ >" from where you display the name.

### Code

```
@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):

    global snipe_message_content
    global snipe_message_author
    global snipe_message_id

    snipe_message_content = message.content
    snipe_message_author = message.author.name
    snipe_message_id = message.id
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

    if message.id == snipe_message_id:
        snipe_message_author = None
        snipe_message_content = None
        snipe_message_id = None

@client.command()
async def snipe(message):
    if snipe_message_content is None:
        await message.channel.send("Theres nothing to snipe.")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Asked by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}", icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{snipe_message_author}")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        return
```

### Output

[image]

#### Edit

Accidentally leaked my discord name and discriminator, changed discriminator to random int. Code still works though.

Comment: Ah, so I was supposed to put 'name' there. My first attempts to display name was to make a reference called 'ping' with 'name' inside but it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, ok. Every time you call a `ctx.author` it returns a [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) or [user](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) object, the links take you to the documentation. Happy Coding!